# add buttons to TableRow programatically and fill in screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I can add TableRow and also some buttons in it programaticaly like below image:
[image]

but I want to figure something like this that button fill in screen:

[image]

and here is my codes:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/Tb1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

and:

```
Button btn1;
private TableLayout buttonTableLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    buttonTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Tb1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
                ((TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row)).removeAllViews();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                TableRow currentTableRow = getTableRow(row);

                for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
                    Button newGuessButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, null);
                    String myName = new String(String.valueOf((row * 5) + column + 1));
                    newGuessButton.setText(myName);

                    currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private TableRow getTableRow(int row) {
    return (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
}
```

and the xml(my_button):

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/newButton" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
```

please give me some advice to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Android `TableRow` class actually extends `LinearLayout` class, so you can use all of `LinearLayout`'s features here.

In this case you can use `android:layout_weight` to equally stretch those buttons. Where you're adding those buttons just add the following piece of code.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.weight = 1;
button.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Or alternatively add these lines to your `button.xml` layout file:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

---

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) say:

> **Equally weighted children**
>
> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the `android:layout_height` of each view to `"0dp"` (for a vertical layout) or the `android:layout_width` of each view to `"0dp"` (for a horizontal layout). Then set the `android:layout_weight` of each view to `"1"`.

Comment: As you see I add the last two lines to my button.xml , but it doesn't works.@Hi I'm Frogatto

Comment: @Beppe Because your way of inflating those buttons needs some change! You shouldn't pass `null` as their parent. Try this : `inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, currentTableRow, false);`